# Why are some page initial loading times are quicker/longer on the same web application?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance, selenium, performance-testing

I am doing a performance test on Selenium IDE on Firefox. All it does is load the AngularJS webpage, save the HAR file (which contains the inital page loading times) and repeat.

I am using AWS web server to host my web application on Apache web server. On the test machine with Selenium, I run the test 100 times and not using it for anything else. I also use incognito mode to clear the cache on every run. Some other information: I dont use CDN, I use gzip compression, my round trip times are about 14ms and I transfer about 1 HTML file, 3 CSS and 7 JS totalling about 300KB compressed.

As shown in the scatter graph (first image is the run, the second image is sorted lowest to highest), why are there some results with faster/high loading times. What could be the reason for this?

Is it due to AngularJS? Browser? Selenium? OS? Bandwidth? Latency? I dont see why those would affect the loading times if every run is similar.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Can be tons of things.... anything from network traffic, to wifi connection, to processes running on your machine.

Comment: it's like the olympics, take away the highest score, take away the lowest score and average the rest, anyway you have your answer with the above comment

Comment: @epascarello yes it could be, but rather than saying it could be a lot of things. I want to know what the things are. As for those mentioned. I am using standard Ethernet and I'm tracking the processes on Linux. There really isnt anything additional running besides selenium and firefox

Comment: It is IMPOSSIBLE to know what the things are without looking at data on your machine, network, servers, etc

Comment: There's a ton of things you have no influence about when talking to some other computer over the internet. Like the internet traffic in your area, package routing and load balancing by your ISP maybe even prioritizing your or other connections *(see internet fast lanes)*, load/peak on the server from an other page, and more ... It's not only about your local client/computer; or even the server at the other end. There's also a roadnet in between the two and somethimes there's a traffic jam.

Comment: Do it manually and reload the page until you get a particularly slow load then look at the details of what is loading slowly vs a fast load. Then maybe you can start to figure out what is loading slow and try to fix it.